# Find last created record by date Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

How can I find when user last time added record and take that record?

Something like this:

```
Comment::where('user_id',Auth::id())->where(HERE I NEED TO GET BIGEST create_at)->first();
```

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the orderby statement:

```
Comment::where('user_id', Auth::id())->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

See:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

For more info.